# Jenkins Active Directory More Secure Authentication Method Required

Tags: active-directory, jenkins

While trying to activate security on a Windows 2008 R2 hosted Jenkins Version 1.514 with the Active Directory plugin version 1.33 I get the following error while trying to logon:

```
INFO: Login attempt failed
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Incorrect password for username  DN=CN=username\,  username,OU=Employees,OU=Users,OU=STUFF,OU=_AccountObjects,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=com:
nested exception is com4j.ComException: 80072028 
A more secure authentication method is required for this server.
```

The part I think is of interest is:

```
nested exception is com4j.ComException: 80072028 
A more secure authentication method is required for this server.
```

I don't see any options for changing the authentication.  I have tried setting the Domain name without any change in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Jenkins, but it sounds like it is attempting an unsigned/simple and that your Domain Controllers are configured to require signing on LDAP connections.

What is the value of `Domain Controller: LDAP server signing requirements` in a `gpresult` under `Computer Configuration | Policies | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | Security Options`?

See the following articles for more information:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935834
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823659 (click on the link entitled `Click here to see information about security settings`
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941829%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

### EDIT

I wonder if you can simply prefix `LDAPS://` and/or append `:636` to the server/domain name you have configured Jenkins to authenticate against?

See the following pages for (potentially) more info:

- [Jenkins Active Directory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin)
- [Jenkins Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)

If it comes down to it, can you disable the signing requirement GPO setting for your domain? If this is not an option, you may look into devoting a DC to Jenkins authentication. That DC would be configured via group policy to allow simple binds. You'd then want to configure a GPO to prevent the DC from registering SRV records. See the second half of [How to Build an AD Replication Delay (Lag) Site](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/paulbergson/archive/2013/05/14/how-to-build-an-ad-replication-delay-lag-site.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yup.  AD is requiring TLS to continue, and Jenkins is only providing a simple password auth to bind.

Comment: I also know nothing about Jenkins, but there is an addon specifically for LDAP you might try instead.  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin

Comment: These helped but in the end we found that you can authenticate jenkins via the teamforge plugin and that is the route we ended up going.